# How do I run a doclet in eclipse

Tags: java, javadoc, doclet

Referring to the examples given in the post : http://www.javaworld.com/jw-08-2000/jw-0818-javadoc.html#resources

Examples in the post : SimpleDoclet and SimpleOrder

I need to know where do I need to place my SimpleDoclet and SimpleOrder and how do I run this doclet to generate output?

I tried using Generate JavaDoc with the following data :

there are two packages : newPack which contains my classes for which javadoc should be generated and oldPack in which SimpleDoclet is Present

Could you please let me know a solution for this?
[image: Javadoc]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem; this is my solution:

1. I create `SimpleDoclet` in the package `codegen.samples`
2. I have exported `SimpleDoclet` as `jarname.jar` in `C:\xx`
3. In Eclipse, set Doclet Name: `codegen.samples.SimpleDoclet` and Doclet class path:
       `c:\xx\jarname.jar`
4. Ask for private visibility (to get all atts and methods)